# Dual GPU laptop, using old OpenGL lib

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, gpu, opengl, dual-gpu

I run OpenGL in Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop with a nvidia card. My laptop has a dual GPU (the nvidia one and the Intel integrated one).

I install the nvidia driver through the CUDA toolkit install (as I need both).

Because my laptop has 2 GPU cards, I have to install the nvidia driver with the **--no-opengl-libs** argument, which states not to replace GL libs (as they are the libs from the non-nvidia GPU).

My problem is that these non-nvidia GL libs are OpenGL 3.0 which is rather old.

What shall I do to make sure I use a more recent version of OpenGL?

The reference to the section of the [**Install Guide** here](https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/8.0/Prod2/docs/sidebar/CUDA_Installation_Guide_Linux-pdf) mentioning --no-opengl-libs is in page 20.

Comment: Are you positive your GPUs even support anything newer then OpenGL.  `-The manual indicates that `no-opengl-libs` is useful in the case your display isn't being driven by a Nvidia GPU, but clearly in your case, that is happening.  So it isn't clear the reason you are using it.

Comment: Actually I am not too sure which GPU is driving my display... But my nvidia gpu is rather advanced and supports GL 4.5 according to [the specs](https://www.geforce.com/hardware/notebook-gpus/geforce-gtx-970m/specifications).

Comment: You need to determine if your 950M is being used or the iGPU (if you have one) is being used